# Changing the routing key of an existing queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

Is it possible to change the routing key of an existing queue in RabbitMQ using a Java client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a queue does not have a routing key. a queue is just a place where messages sit.

the routing key lives in the binding between an exchange and a queue

you need to create a new binding between your exchange and queue, and delete the old binding if you no longer need it

Comment: And if that queue is not empty, is it possible to move messages from there to another queue?

Comment: you have a few options for that: 1) write code that manually takes the message and re-publishes it, 2) let the current code finish processing from the old queue (called "draining" the queue), or 3) use the "shovel" plugin https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html